# Java calculator program using JTextField issue

Tags: java, swing

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CalField extends JPanel {
    private JTextField field;

    public CalField() {

        setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 5, 5));
        field = new JTextField(20);
        field.setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        field.setEditable(true);
        add(field);

    }

    public JTextField getField() {
        return field;
    }

    public void setField(String text) {
        field.setText(text);
        System.out.print(text);

    }
}
```

CalButton Class:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class CalButton extends JPanel {
    private JButton[] buttons;
    private static final String[] buttonNames = { "7", "8", "9", "/", "4", "5",
            "6", "*", "1", "2", "3", "-", "0", ".", "=", "+" };
    private CalField calField;

    public CalButton() {
        buttons = new JButton[buttonNames.length];
        setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4, 3, 3));
        calField = new CalField();
        ButtonListener handler = new ButtonListener();
        for (int i = 0; i < buttonNames.length; i++) {
            buttons[i] = new JButton(buttonNames[i]);
            buttons[i].setFont(new Font("SansSerif", Font.BOLD, 20));

            add(buttons[i]);
            buttons[i].addActionListener(handler);
        }

    }

    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (buttons[0].getActionCommand() == event.getActionCommand()) {
                calField.setField(event.getActionCommand());
//              System.out.print(buttons[0].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[1].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[1].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[2].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[2].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[3].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[3].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[4].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[4].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[5].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[5].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[6].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[6].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[7].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[7].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[8].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[8].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[9].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[9].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[10].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[10].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[11].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[11].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[12].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[12].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[13].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[13].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[14].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[14].getActionCommand());
            } else if (buttons[15].getActionCommand() == event
                    .getActionCommand()) {
                System.out.print(buttons[15].getActionCommand());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Calculator  Class:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame application = new JFrame("Calculator");
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.setSize(250, 200);

        CalField calField = new CalField();
        CalButton calButton = new CalButton();

        application.add(calField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        application.add(calButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        application.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

In this program, In the `JButton`'s actionListener i called the CalField class's `setText()` method to set the corresponding button's text in the `JTextField`.

But the text showing in the console but not showing in the `TextField`. What can i do now? help me someone please.

Comment: So if you press the `7` button the `CalField` does not show anything?

Comment: @jgitter `JTextField#setText` is a bound field, this means that it will schedule it's own repaint when called

Comment: @MadProgrammer You are correct.  Removing flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in your `Calculator` class, you create and add an instance of `CalField` to a `JFrame`...

```
public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame application = new JFrame("Calculator");
        application.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        application.setSize(250, 200);

        CalField calField = new CalField();
        CalButton calButton = new CalButton();

        application.add(calField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        application.add(calButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        application.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Then, in your `CalButton` class, you create ANOTHER instance of `CalField`...

```
public class CalButton extends JPanel {
    //...
    private CalField calField;

    public CalButton() {
        //...
        calField = new CalField();
        //...
    }
```

This never gets added to anything, but is the instance you try and update.  This instance of `CalField` has nothing to do with the instance of `CalField` which you aded to the frame.

Instead, you need to pass an instance of `CalField` to `CalButton`

```
public class CalButton extends JPanel {
    //...
    private CalField calField;

    public CalButton(CalField calField) {
        //...
        this.calField = calField;
        //...
    }
```

Then in your `Calculator` class, you would pass the instance of `CalField` you created to the instance of `CalButton`...

```
CalField calField = new CalField();
CalButton calButton = new CalButton(calField);

application.add(calField, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
application.add(calButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This creates a relationship between the class which are actually displayed on the screen

> Now when i clicking on a button this shows the text but when i click another button it overrides the previous one's text. How to solve this problem so that the overriding does'nt occur

That's because `setText` does just that, it sets the text of field, replacing what ever was there before it.

Instead, when you call `setField`, you should append the current text in the field with the new next, something like...

```
public void setField(String text) {
    field.setText(field.getText() + text);
    System.out.print(text);

}
```

but I'd probably change the method to `appendField` so it's clear what it does

Also, because most of your `if-else` statements in your `actionPerformed` don't really do anything and they do to is pretty much the same thing,

```
if (buttons[0].getActionCommand() == event.getActionCommand()) {
    calField.setField(event.getActionCommand());
} else if (buttons[1].getActionCommand() == event.getActionCommand()) {
    System.out.print(buttons[1].getActionCommand());
} else if (buttons[2].getActionCommand() == ...
```

you could just do something more like...

```
calField.setField(event.getActionCommand());
```

Now, you might need to add in some `if` statements for special keys, like `=` and clear, but all the other numeric buttons, only need to do the above, this should greatly reduce the repeated code and make maintaining the code easier

Comment: Yes @MadProgrammer it's working. but i'm facing a new problem now. Now when i clicking on a button this shows the text but when i click another button it overrides the previous one's text. How to solve this problem so that the overriding does'nt occur.

Comment: Of course it does, what did you think setText does? When the actionPerformed event occurs, get the current text from the textField, append the results of the button which triggered the event, the use this value when you call setText

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer [MadProgrammer](http://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) for your kind help. it's really very helpful for me.

Answer (score -1):

Most of your if- clauses in the actionPerformed method fail to try to set the text.
All you need is:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Object src = event.getSource();
    calField.setField( ((JButton)src).getActionCommand());
}
```

or even:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    calField.setField( event.getActionCommand());
}
```

Comment: This does not answer his question.

Comment: @jgitter Why doesn't  "Most of your if- clauses in the actionPerformed method fail to try to set the text" answer the question? Of course, he also needs to do as MadProgrammer said and not create anotherCalField.

Comment: yea @FredK I'm facing new problem now. MadProgrammer's code is  working. but i'm facing a new problem now. Now when i clicking on a button this shows the text but when i click another button it overrides the previous one's text. How to solve this problem so that the overriding does'nt occur.